# Make a clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var li = $('.someDiv li');
    li.toggle(function () {
        li.children("div").hide();
        $(this).children("div").fadeIn(700);
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("div").fadeOut(300);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="someDiv">
<ul>
<li>Title <div style="display:none;">Description <a href="#">Something</a></div></li>
<li>Title <div style="display:none;">Description <a href="#">Something</a></div></li>
<li>Title <div style="display:none;">Description <a href="#">Something</a></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

There are links inside divs, but when a div is visible the links are not clickable, because the clicking just toggles the div.
How make the links work?

Comment: You need to add some relevant code. What is the HTML? Maybe add it to a Fiddle?

Comment: It would be great to see what links you are talking about.

Comment: Also, why would you make the list elements clickable...?

Comment: It seems you need to capture the event of a click on "a" HTML element via JavaScript and stop the propagation of this "click" event in order the "li" element does not receive it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use toggle, check the event to see if it is an anchor, if it is ignore the click.

```
$(function () {
    $('.someDiv').on("click","li", function(e){
        var li = $(this);

        if ( $(e.target).is("a") ) return;

        li.toggleClass("open");
        var divs = li.children("div").stop();

        if(li.hasClass("open")) {
            divs.fadeIn(700);
       } else {
            divs.fadeOut(300);
       } 

    });
});
```